# CakePHP: question about Cookies expire

Tags: cakephp, cookies

if 1 cookie is create by         `$this->Cookie->write('Rating', $cookie, true, '+1 months');`
after 15 day, I read :

```
 $this->Cookie->read('Rating');
    do somthing .... this   
$this->Cookie->write('Rating', $cookie, true, '+1 months');
```

Then now expire of rating cookies is 15 days or 1 month ?

Answer (score 0):

It should still be 1 month.